# Spring Security fetches lazy loaded properties on Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, jwt

I am new to Spring Security and using Springboot, Mysql to create a sample application with authentication using jwt. However, I have noticed that on sign in request, when the authentication happens, Spring security is retrieving all the lazy-loaded properties (in my case Roles, Personal Details). Is there any way to let Spring security know to ignore making an additional call to get PersonalDetails.

App properties

```
 logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
 logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

User Model

```
public class User {

    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user")
    private PersonalDetails personalDetails;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

   // getters and setters
}
```

AuthController

```
    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signin(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

         Authentication authentication = 
                 authenticationManager
                       .authenticate(
                          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                 loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(), 
                                 loginRequest.getPassword()
                        )
          );

         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

         String jwtToken = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);

         return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwtToken));

      }
```

Comment: Instead of writing User and UserDetailsService have you tried org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService ? this might load only security related details and your User model can extend to this model if required.

Comment: Yes, i have not included it here but my user details service extends Spring sec User detail service

Comment: Ok , but what about User class ? is it from Spring security itself?